# OAuth to launch AWS Instance on behalf of user

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

I have a system of hosts that work together to demonstrate our product.

In order to have a customer run a test environment, I need to launch 4 instances for them to "play".  So far I have had to pay for launching the hosts.

Is there a way that the customer can authorize me to launch preconfigure instances on their behalf?

I was thinking they could click a button and OAuth with my web app and then I could launch the instances for them.  Is this the wrong approach?

Thanks!

Comment: they could create a trust relation ship with your account and authorize one of your IAM users to create certain resources in their account. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html Here's something on those lines

Comment: Thanks!  this looks very interesting and also kind of complicated.  Is that something they could do from my website or would they have to have a conversation with our support people to make that happen.